# Deleting a Node after a given position and head in a singly linked list

Tags: java

Did I miss anything in the below code . The code is about deleting a Node from a linkedlist given its head and position. My program is not passing all the test cases .

```
Node Delete(Node head, int position) {

   // Node temp=head;
    int count=1;
    if(position==0){
       head=head.next;
       return head; 
    }
    if(position==1){
        head=head.next.next;
        return head;
    }
    if(position>1){
        Node temp=head;
        while(count<position){
            count++;
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        temp.next=temp.next.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

**Input**

4

3

1 2 3

0

3

1 2 3

1

3

1 2 3

2

5

4 3 2 5 1

2

**My output**

23

12
4351

**Expected output**

23
13
12
4351

Comment: what test cases should your code satisfy?

Comment: Try looking at the Java code [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-linked-list-node-at-a-given-position/).

Comment: If the returned Node is supposed to be the new head of the linkedList, then what you're doing wrong is that you're deleting every node up to the position, instead of just deleting the node at the position. `position == 0` is the only case where you should return a modified `head`.

Comment: And what test cases does your code *not* satisfy?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Node Delete(Node head, int position) {
           Node node = head;
           Node prevNode = null;
           int index = 0;
        if (head == null && position == 0){
             return head;
           }
         if (head != null && position == 0){
               head = null;
               head = node.next;

           }
           if (position > 0){
           while(index<position){
               prevNode = node;
               node = node.next;
               index = index + 1;
           }
           prevNode.next = node.next;
           node = null;
           }

         return head;
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment to what changed in your answer compared to op's code

Comment: Use the previous node and current node two variables, So that when deleting node at given position then assign the next node to as the current node. And check condition on when given position is greater than zero then use the while loop and iterate until given position node is not find then assign :- prevNode.next = node.next;
           node = null;